# Modal pop-up again when closed

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm building a filter using react-native modal. I pass a bool variable as props and when I check the value I find that it has been updated, meanwhile the modal disappears and pop-up again with a very strange behavior.

**1st pop-up: Everything is working fine**

**2nd pop-up: Nothing is clickable besides switch buttons**

Here's my component code:

```
/** @format */

import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback,Switch,AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TagSelect } from 'react-native-tag-select';
import { Languages, withTheme, Tools, Color, English,French, Config, Constants } from "@common";
import { ProductCatalog, ProductList, ProductTags, ProductLanguage, LogoSpinner } from "@components";
import styles from "./styles";
import Item from "../../components/ChipItem";
import reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";
import SelectBox from 'react-native-multi-selectbox'
import { xorBy } from 'lodash'

const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height


let FILTER_LANGUAGES = [];
Config.languages.forEach((value)=>{
  FILTER_LANGUAGES.push({id:value.id,label:value.text});
});

const ebookTypes_FR = [
  {
    id:"book",
    label:"Livre"
  },
  {
    id:"video",
    label:"Video"
  },
  {
    id:"article",
    label:"Article"
  },
  
]


const ebookTypes_EN = [
  {
    id:"book",
    label:"Book"
  },
  {
    id:"video",
    label:"Video"
  },
  {
    id:"article",
    label:"Article"
  },
  
]

class CategoryFilters extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      // scrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
      // expanded: true,
      value: 2000,
      selectedId: -1,
      show:false,
      hasAudio:false,
      bestSeller:false,
      selectedLangArr:[],
      selectedLangs: [],
      selectedTypes: [],
      LangFilters: [],
      TypeFilters:[],
      localLang: "",
      loading:true,
 
    };
    this.filter = {
      hasAudio : this.state.hasAudio,
      bestSeller :this.state.bestSeller,
    };
  }

  show = ()=>{
    this.setState({show:true});
  }
  close = ()=>{
      this.setState({show:false});
  }
  onMultiChangeLang (array) {
    return (item) => {
      this.setState({ 
        selectedLangs:(xorBy(array, [item], 'id'))
    })
    }
  }

  onMultiChangeType (array) {
    reactotron.log("selectedTypes ==>",this.state.selectedTypes);
    return (item) => {
      this.setState({ 
      selectedTypes:(xorBy(array, [item], 'id'))
    })
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.currentText !== this.props.currentText) {
      this.setState({
        hasAudio:false,
        bestSeller:false,
      })
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const localLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LocalLang');

    this.setState({
      localLang,
      loading:false,
    });
  }

  onFilterList = ()=>{
    try{
      reactotron.log("this props",this.props);
      this.onSelectLanguage();
      this.onSelectType();
      let ArrayFilters ='';
  
      this.setState({
        changedFilters:'true'
      }, () => {
  
        reactotron.log("ARRAY FILTEEEEEEEEEEEEEERS", ArrayFilters);
        ArrayFilters = this.state.TypeFilters.concat(this.state.LangFilters)
        reactotron.log("ARRAY FILTEEEEEEEEEEEEEERS AFTER", ArrayFilters);
        reactotron.log("this filters & ArrayFilters before", this.filter,ArrayFilters );
        this.filter = {
          hasAudio : this.state.hasAudio,
          bestSeller :this.state.bestSeller,
        };
        
  
        this.filter = {...this.filter, ...ArrayFilters}
  
        reactotron.log("this filters", this.filter);
        this.props.updateCategoryFilter(this.filter)
      });
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }


    
  }

renderOutsideTouchable(onTouch){
    const view = <View style={{flex:1, width:'100%'}} />
    if(!onTouch)return view
    return(
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onTouch} style={{flex:1, width:'100%'}} >
            {view}
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}

  render() {

    if(this.state.loading){
      return( null );
    }else{
      let selectedLanguages = this.state.selectedLangs;
      let selectedTypesRender = this.state.selectedTypes;
      const {onTouchOutside, navigation} =this.props
      const { categories, tags, list } = this.props;
      const { selectedLang, selectedType } = this.state;
  
      const {
        theme: {
          colors: { background, text },
        },
        language,
      } = this.props;
  
      
      const toggleSwitchAudio = () => {
        this.setState({hasAudio:!this.state.hasAudio})
        this.filter = {...this.filter, hasAudio:!this.state.hasAudio}
      };
  
      const toggleSwitchBest = () => {
        this.setState({bestSeller:!this.state.bestSeller})
        this.filter = {...this.filter, bestSeller:!this.state.bestSeller}
      };
  
      return (
        this.props.show &&
        <Modal
          animationType={'fade'}
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.props.show}
          onRequestClose={()=>{this.close()}}
          >
          <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#000000AA', justifyContent:'flex-end'}}>
            {this.renderOutsideTouchable(onTouchOutside)}
            <ScrollView 
              scrollEnabled={false}
              style={[
                styles.container, { 
                backgroundColor: background, 
                width:'100%', 
                borderTopRightRadius:10,
                borderTopLeftRadius:10, 
                paddingHorizontal:10,
                maxHeight: deviceHeight * 0.8,
              }]}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between',}}>
              <Text style={[styles.FilterLabel, { color: text }]}>
                {Languages[this.state.localLang].filterBy}
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnClear, {marginRight:20}} onPress={this.clearFilter}>
                <Text style={styles.clearFilter}>{Languages[this.state.localLang].Reset}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
  
            {/* <ProductCatalog
              categories={categories}
              onSelectCategory={this.onSelectCategory}
            /> */}
            {/* <ProductTags tags={tags} onSelectTag={this.onSelectTag} /> */}
  
            
            
             <View>
             {/* <ProductLanguage ebookLang={ebookLang} onSelectLanguage={this.onSelectLanguage}/> */}
               
              <View 
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  marginHorizontal: 15,
                  marginVertical: 10,
                  flexWrap: "wrap",
                }}>
                   <Text style={{color: text,fontSize:14,fontFamily:Constants.fontFamily,fontWeight:"bold",}}>
                    {Languages[this.state.localLang].labelLang}
                  </Text>
                  <TagSelect
                    value={this.state.selectedLangs}
                    containerStyle={{flexDirection:'row',flex:1,justifyContent:'flex-start',alignContent:'center',alignItems:'flex-start',marginTop:10,}}
                    onItemPress={(item)=> {
                        const index = selectedLanguages.indexOf(item);
                        
                        if(index == -1){
                            selectedLanguages.push(item);
                        }else{
                            selectedLanguages.splice(index,1);
                        }
                        onMultiChangeLang();
                    }}
                    data={FILTER_LANGUAGES}
                    max={10}
                  />
              </View>
              <View 
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  marginHorizontal: 15,
                  marginVertical: 10,
                  flexWrap: "wrap",
                }}>
                  <Text style={{color: text,fontSize:14,fontFamily:Constants.fontFamily,fontWeight:"bold",}}>
                    {Languages[this.state.localLang].labelType}
                  </Text>
                  <TagSelect
                    value={selectedTypesRender}
                    containerStyle={{flexDirection:'row',flex:1,justifyContent:'flex-start',alignContent:'center',alignItems:'flex-start',marginTop:10,}}
                    onItemPress={(item)=> {
                        const index = selectedTypesRender.indexOf(item);
                        if(index == -1){
                          selectedTypesRender.push(item);
                        }else{
                          selectedTypesRender.splice(index,1);
                        }
                        onMultiChangeType();
                    }}
                    data={ebookTypes_FR}
                    max={10}
                  />
              </View>
              <View 
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection:'row',
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  paddingTop:10,
                  paddingBottom:10
                }}>
                <View style={{ marginLeft:20 }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: text,fontSize:14,fontFamily:Constants.fontFamily,fontWeight:"bold", }} >{Languages[this.state.localLang].withAudio}</Text>
                </View>
                <Switch 
                  style={{marginRight:20}}
                  trackColor={{ false: "#C0C0C0", true: "#3FC1BE" }}
                  thumbColor={this.state.hasAudio ? "#f4f3f4" : "#f4f3f4"}
                  ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                  onValueChange={toggleSwitchAudio}
                  value={this.state.hasAudio}
                />
              </View>
              <View 
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection:'row',
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}>
                <View style={{marginLeft:20}}>
                  <Text style={{ color: text,fontSize:14,fontFamily:Constants.fontFamily,fontWeight:"bold", }} >{Languages[this.state.localLang].BestSeller}</Text>
                </View>
                <Switch 
                  style={{marginRight:20}}
                  trackColor={{ false: "#C0C0C0", true: "#3FC1BE" }}
                  thumbColor={this.state.bestSeller ? "#f4f3f4" : "#f4f3f4"}
                  ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                  onValueChange={toggleSwitchBest}
                  value={this.state.bestSeller}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
              <>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnFilter} onPress={this.onFilter}>
                  <Text style={styles.filterText}>{Languages[this.state.localLang].Filter}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnClear} onPress={onTouchOutside}>
                  <Text style={styles.cancel, {color:Color.primary}}>{Languages[this.state.localLang].Cancel}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
        
      );
    }
  }

  onSelectCategory = (item) => {
    this.filter = { ...this.filter, category: item.id };
  };

  onSelectTag = (item) => {
    this.filter = { ...this.filter, tag: item.id };
  };

  onSelectLanguage = (item) =>{
    this.setState({
      LangFilters: this.state.selectedLangs
    })

  }

  onSelectType = (item) =>{
    this.setState({
      TypeFilters: this.state.selectedTypes
    })

  }

  onSelectAudio = (item) =>{
    this.filter = {...this.filter, hasAudio:item}
  }


  onFilter = () => {
    this.onFilterList()
    this.props.onTouchOutside()
  };

  clearFilter = () => {

    //this.componentDidMount()
    for (let prop in this.filter) {
      delete this.filter[prop];
    }
    this.setState({
      
      isEnabled:false,
      selectedTypes:[],
      selectedLangs:[]
    }  
      )
    this.props.onTouchOutside()
  };

  
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: state.categories.list,
    tags: state.tags.list,
    ebookLang: state.ebookLang,
    ebookTypes:state.ebookTypes,
    CategoryFilter:state.CategoryFilter
  };
};

function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  const { netInfo } = stateProps;
  const { dispatch } = dispatchProps;
  const { actions } = require("@redux/TagRedux");
  const { actions : CategoryiltersActions } = require("@redux/CategoryFilterRedux");


  return {
    ...ownProps,
    ...stateProps,
    fetchTags: () => {
      actions.fetchTags(dispatch);
    },
    updateCategoryFilter: (filters) => {
      dispatch(CategoryiltersActions.updateCategoryFilter(filters));
    },
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  undefined,
  mergeProps
)(withTheme(CategoryFilters));
```

And here's the behavior I'm having:

[image]

**UPDATE: This behavior is only in iOS.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have much time to read the whole code at the moment unfortunately. But from what you have written I have a doubt, maybe it can help you anyway. If you pass a true or false value as a parameter from one component to another, make sure you also pass a function to change it from the parent component rather than just updating it in the child. Hope this helps you

Comment: Indeed I update the value from the parent component, I guess there's an issue with the transparent parameter in react-native 0.63.2 in the modal component